# Auto update in window application in setup deployement dot Project without using third party service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer

I just started my windows application in Visual Studio 2008.

I also added a setup & deployement project to create a msi file.
But now there where some changes in my code and so i have to update the application.

How can I make this project "auto updateable" for the client.

Comment: you can combine set up and source project in one solution. and in application folder of set up, add source project's output

Comment: ClickOnce is what you need. There are lots of questions on that here.

Comment: ClickOnce has a very limited story.  You have no idea if this meets his requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can try ClickOnce deployment provided in Visual Studio.

[ClickOnce ad MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)